# Integration QlikView and python

Tags: qlikview

How can I perform python Integration in QlikView or can anyone suggest me any blog for this or link?

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: have done forecasting using (Random Forest Regressor and knn) in jupyter now I want to integrate my out in Qlikview.

Answer (score 1):

The basic help page about Analytics Connections (which is how you integrate Python) is [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2019/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Analytic_connections.htm). You may also find the page on [writing Server Side Exentions](https://github.com/qlik-oss/server-side-extension) helpful, including [getting started in python](https://github.com/qlik-oss/server-side-extension/blob/master/examples/python/GetStarted.md) page.

Hope that helps.